# How to update Connection created using patterns in Graphiti

Tags: java, swt, jface, eclipse-emf, eclipse-gef

I am using ConnectionPattern to create connections.

My Connection class Extends `AbstractConnectionPattern`.
Everything works fine but when I change value of business object associated with it (using `TransactionalEditingDomain`) changes are not updated in the Diagram.

Changes to the business object are done via a dialog box that pops up when double clicked on the connection.

Changes made are not reflected in the tooltip as well as in ConnectionDecorator.

I am new to this framework I have tried with helper methods from AbstractConnectionPattern class as well but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a notification event fired once you change the business model. Put a breakpoint in the #handleNotificationEvent(...) method or #handlePropertyChange(...) method on your editpart object corresponding to a connection (controller). The view should be updated there based on the change to the model. I suspect that this part is missing.

Comment: I know where to update but don't know how to update connection decorator and connection   in graphiti.